# Yii2 : Is it posible to change default parameter name in search URL?

Tags: yii2, default-value

I have change `formName/Modal Class Name` in below search URL like `SubjectMaster` to `SM`.

When I search/filter data using `GET` method at time change my required name.

> http://demo.local/report/subject?SubjectMaster[year]=3&SubjectMaster[course]=&SubjectMaster[session]=&SubjectMaster[status]=

Comment: so whats the problem or what's the question in regards to changing form name ?

Comment: I have change `SubjectMaster` name, and it is my `Modal Class Name`. It changed when i have filter data using `GET` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to override the `formName` method on the model.

```
class SubjectMaster extends ... 
{
    public function formName()
    {
        return 'SM';
    }
}
```

Comment: Any `issues/problem` raised, when i use override formName() method?